# Horizontally Center a jQuery dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have an example [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/popout.html).

When I open the window, it is vertically centered, but the horizontal center is far down. I want to get it centered on the screen when it pops up.

This is the jscript...

```
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 1011,
            height: 'auto',
            show: 'fade',
            hide: 'fade',
            buttons: {
                "Dismiss": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

I've tried using `position: 'middle',`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

look at the documentation of `position`
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

here is how you use it:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 1011,
    height: 'auto',
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
    buttons: {
        "Dismiss": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

> I read through the documentation. I wanted the dialog box to be
>   centered, in the middle of the page... not centered, and at the very
>   top. Just in the middle of the page. I've tried center left, center
>   center ...How come there's just no center middle? – webfrogs Sep 6 '13
>   at 22:58
>
> ```
>        Someone please come back... – webfrogs Sep 7 '13 at 2:04
> ```

You can use any of the following to make it in the middle of the page

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 1011,
    height: 'auto',
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    position: {my: "center top", at:"center middle", of: window },
    buttons: {
        "Dismiss": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

OR

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 1011,
    height: 'auto',
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    position: ['center', 'middle'],
    buttons: {
        "Dismiss": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I read through the documentation. I wanted the dialog box to be centered, in the middle of the page... not centered, and at the very top. Just in the middle of the page. I've tried `center left`, `center center` ...How come there's just no `center middle`?

Comment: `position: {my: "center top", at:"center middle", of: window },` I updated the answer